# How to display HashSet objects in preserve order?

Tags: java

Basically `HashSet` following insertion order is not preserved, but I want to display `HashSet` objects in the form of preserve order in Java.

Is it possible? If yes then can you please share some ideas.

Thanks in advance

JP.

Comment: Just use a LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinkedHashSet it `preserves` the order of insertion.

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {
        set.add( i+"" );
    }
    // insertion order is 0,1,2,3,4
    for(String str : set)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    //output 0,1,2,3,4
```

Comment: I have already Set, but I want to display that Set in the same order in java. Can you please share a piece of code.   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use LinkedHashSet instead of HashSet. [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) will maintain the insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

For Set there is `LinkedHashSet` and for Map there is `LinkedHashMap` - both retain the order in which items were inserted although there is a very small performance impact.

There is also the option of `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` which do not retain the order in which elements were inserted but instead keeps them in a specified order (either their natural ordering or as specified by a comparator).

Answer (score 1):

If the order of insertion is important, maybe you should use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which preserves insertion order.